# simplify re.compile for matching any long character

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

`[10/Jul/2019:00:45:18 +0900] "POST /auth/identity/success HTTP/1.1"`

I want to extract everything inside ""

for the date I used 
`re.compile('\[(\d+\/\w\w\w\/\d\d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s\+\d\d\d\d)\]')`

for the string inside "" instead of matching one by one I am hoping if there is way to match say 10 character with one regex command.

I've done `re.compile('(\"[A-Z]\s[\w\/]\s[\w\/\"])')`

What I am trying to do:

```
\" matches "
[A-Z] matches 4 character (but actually match only one character)
\s for whitespace
[\w\/] for matching everything in /auth/../success
[\w\/\"] for HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: Looks like you're new to regex. I recommend experimenting and troubleshooting here: https://regex101.com/ . To answer your question about matching characters multiple times, what you're looking for are quantifiers. Put `{n}` after a character or group and it will match n times. `a{3}` matches `aaa` for example.

Comment: but problem is number of character will be different for each line

Comment: So use `+` (1 or more) or `*` (0 or more).